# How do I integrate (3rd party) SDK via config.xml for Ionic/Cordova?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I'm using [this plugin](https://github.com/InteractiveObject/StarIOPlugin) and integrated it as [this demo-application](https://github.com/InteractiveObject/StarIOPluginDemo) did. That uses the [Star SDK](http://www.starmicronics.com/support/sdkdocumentation.aspx).

But how can I change something in my *config.xml* that the SDK is always added/loaded when I do an Ionic build? Because now we all have to re-add it to our project when we build from a different MacBook.

It's now specific for the StarIO SDK, but I think someone else maybe had the same struggle when adding an SDK.

**Edit:** Every time before I archive an iOS app from my Ionic project, I have to do the following manually:

- Include framework and bundles (SDK) in my Xcode project
- Link with some default framework/libraries like: `ExternalAccessory.framework`
- Setup external accessory protocols in `info.plist`

This is lots of work, especially when we have multiple builds per week. And we don't always deploy on the same machine, and it's hard to forget a step.

I see this with a lot of Cordova packages, that you need to do some things manually when there is no Podfile, for example, or it always needs some configuration.

Comment: I work with Cordova and Ionic daily and I have a hard time figuring out what you're trying to ask.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's something StarIOPlugin creator should do instead of telling you to add the Star SDK manually. Start by adding an issue on StarIOPlugin's github repository.

If the author doesn't want to do it, then you can fork the plugin and update it yourself.

You should start by adding the `StarIO.framework` to the `src/ios` folder

Now all you need can be done editing the `plugin.xml` file

First add this line to the plugin.xml to copy the framework to the Xcode project

```
<source-file src="src/ios/StarIO.framework" framework="true" />
```

Then add this two lines to add Bluetooth and ExternalAccesory frameworks

```
<framework src="CoreBluetooth.framework" />
<framework src="ExternalAccesory.framework" />
```

And finally, to write on the info.plist use

```
<config-file target="*-Info.plist" parent="UISupportedExternalAccessoryProtocols">
    <array>
        <string>jp.star-m.starpro</string>
    </array>
</config-file>
```

I've not tested, but should be enough.

Comment: is there sample like this for capacitor?..

Answer (score 1):

I am the developer who initially contributed the iOS support and I don't see why you would need to do the configuration you mention more than once. Are you removing and adding the iOS platform from your project? That is the only thing that should cause that.

There are a few reasons that I didn't include the library in my original PR. But my reasoning could very well be flawed.

Here is what I was thinking...

- I wasn't sure that including their library in another open source project complies with the Star software license.
- Including the framework would forever obligate contributors to keep the framework up to date with releases from Star
- There are multiple frameworks for iOS that will work with this plugin, one for regular bluetooth printers and one for the mPOP. So including one of the frameworks could limit the users ability to integrate with all possible platforms.

Regardless, the documentation should be improved to help other developers with the same issues.

Comment: He said that he had to re add this if he tried to build from another mac, if you are on a team or have a few development machines you have to do all the manual steps on every machine. And sometimes there are bugs on platform update and you have to remove and re add. About your points, on 1, you are distributing their framework, not their code, so there should not be license problems. 2, yeah, contributors should update the framework from time to time. 3 I don't think I fully understand that point.

Comment: On point #1, the framework is not compiled. It is the source code from StarIO that I would have to include, and their license says that you can't redistribute their code. But let me know if I am misinterpreting this.

On point #3, what I was trying to explain is that there are two different SDKs that the plugin will work with, and it depends on the exact hardware you are trying to integrate with. So, I didn't want to lock everyone into one or the other since they will need to choose what SDK to use. Hopefully that makes more sense.

Comment: As the question was iOS only, on #1, they provide a .framework, not actual code, so I think it's ok to distribute. I've just seen that they provide the android code, but they provide the .jar too, so I think it's ok to distribute the .jar (I think, but I'm not a lawyer). For #3 you are right, I didn't notice that they provide different SDKs, I just downloaded the first one I saw.

Answer (score -1):

I guess you have to do some manual work here. If it is a simple command you can create a "script" in the package.json and run it with "npm run script_name".

Depending on your specific needs you could also add a task to the gulpfile.js (this is used by the ionic build) or write a JS script which gets executed with a specific Cordova lifecycle step. [Check this out](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/dev/guide/appdev/hooks/) for more details on this. The default Ionic project has an [example hook](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-app-base/tree/master/hooks/after_prepare) you can check out for inspiration.

Comment: You can still do what you asked for with a hook, its just not really comfortable, e.g.: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/diegonetto/generator-ionic/master/templates/hooks/after_prepare/update_platform_config.js